# Give full controll over S3 object to another account

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 object in account A and I want to give full control over this object to Account B.
I have tried setting up policies, but I cannot manage it and I am confused.
Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: with aws console make S3 Bucket public and give read write permission to everyone.but its not good for security so you can add other user security and access key so perticular that user can access your bucket

Comment: What do you mean by "give full control over this object"? Do you want to include PutObject, DeleteObject, GetObject? Anything else? If it is just for the object, they won't be able to view the bucket in the console, but they will still be able to access/manage the object via the AWS CLI and API -- is that acceptable?

Comment: Apologies for being unclear, I wanted to change ownership of a certain object in S3, I wanted the owner to be a different account with full S3 access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Account B did not had any S3 access and by providing access I was able to change object ownership by copying over the object on top of it's self.
Thank you all for the replies, it did help.

Answer (score 1):

You can give access to user in Account A to objects in S3 bucket of Account B, by enabling the cross-account access. The below AWS documentation clearly gives the information of S3 bucket granting cross-account access. [Bucket Owner Granting Cross-Account Bucket Permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html)